# Risk of Installing a Custom ROM, with no more future updates

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom

What is the risk of installing a custom ROM whose build has been terminated by the developer(which may be a stable). I think no more future build updates will be available. I know there will be having higher chances of security risk. What are the other risks should I bother?

1. As there is no security updates further, how to can I use it securely?
2. ROM is the one which I have previously used, possibly having least bugs. Is it safe for continuing or switch to other ROM?

Device : rooted Redmi 1S, nougat 7.1.1

Comment: Having a bug still listed by the dev? For example I still need CM13 for Xposed, but the final update doesn't fix half-critical bugs like WiFi disconnect, etc. - this happens to one of my devices.

Answer (score 0):

Well using a custom ROM which won't get updates means you will have to live with it's bugs (if there is any) or fix it yourself if you know how.
In my opinion biggest 'risk' when you use custom ROM is voiding warranty because you need to unlock bootloader. I don't worry about security updates because I'm carefull what .apk I install and on what link I click, also I don't think I'm interesting to attackers, and I'm sure you aren't too. If you have super sensitive information than you should use phone which get updates regularly, and do not root it or use unlock bootloader. But however even than if you not look on what you click you can let someone in. So don't worry about securty updates if you use your brain.